# Illustrator for Beginners

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm pretty good at photoshop (got at least 7 years experience with it any how), but i'm looking into broadening my horizons, and with my job I could use a few more tricks up my sleeve. So I was wondering, does anyone know of a decent BEGINNERS tutorials area for Illustrator, i've never even attempted to make something in Illustrator but think that's probably the best thing for me to learn right now.

P.S.: Preferably free tutorials if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't neglect books. Deke McLelland's "Illustrator 1-on-1" books are what I recommend most often to people wanting to get started with Illustrator. You get all of the sample files, so you can work along with the book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adobe has lots of free resources for beginners. I've used some of them before. They're pretty easy to understand and they touch on everything that's important for beginners as well as get you started on doing neat stuff. Here is what's available for Illustrator CS4 and CS5:

**Adobe Illustrator Help Documentation**

- CS4: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Illustrator/14.0/
- CS5: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/illustrator/cs/using/index.html

**Adobe Illustrator Getting Started Page**

- CS5: http://www.adobe.com/support/illustrator/gettingstarted/index.html

**AdobeTV Illustrator Video Tutorials**

- CS4: http://tv.adobe.com/show/learn-illustrator-cs4/
- CS5: http://tv.adobe.com/show/learn-illustrator-cs5/

Comment: forgot about AdobeTV...that good also. I prefer video tutorials, and books sometimes, but not for learning software... for more in depth stuff...

Answer (score 3):

A good starting point is to educate yourself about the diffrence between Raster and Vector Graphics. And then...

The best tutorials I would recommend would be from Lynda.com :
Look for the Illustrator CSX(depending on what version you have) Essential Training and then proceed to mare advanced titles.

http://www.lynda.com/Illustrator-training-tutorials/227-0.html

You can also try Total Training.com , the are simmilar to Lynda.com, you can start with the basics and then go to guru stuff...

http://www.totaltraining.com/prod/adobe/illustrator.asp

Or another nice one is Real world Illustrator[thx to AG for this one]:

http://rwillustrator.blogspot.com/

For some diffrent stuff you can try some none-video tutorials from websites like:

http://vector.tutsplus.com/

And just google for illustrator tutorial and you'll find tons of stuff, maybe even in your native language.
(if your not enlish, I was lucky and I did found some tutorials in Romanian :D so if you know romanian these are very cool:

http://creativemonkeyz.com/category/tutoriale/illustrator/

)