# How can i make a vector from really small jpgs

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, jpg

i have really really small jpg images, and i want to know how can i make a vector in AI. They are like 31mm W and 14 H.

Thank you so much, guys :)

Comment: Redraw them. Without seeing images, that's the best I can offer.

Comment: Size in mm doesn't tell us much. If they are >300dpi with this size, you should have enough *pixels* to take the usual route: Autotrace.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. You use Illustrators basic Drawing Tools to trace the Images. Like that you get a redrawn vector-version of your image. There's lots of Information about the usage of basic Illustrator drawingtools [here on StackExchange.](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4488/illustrator-for-beginners)
2. You use the Autotrace function of illustrator. In the **Object** menu you find *Image Trace*. Use it while you have your picture selected. There's Options on how your Image is retraced in the Optionbar ontop  of your screen. Tutorial: [Image Trace in Adobe Illustrator CS6.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MiHAh56apJY)

I hope this helps.